# errors on shell

Tags: scripting, tcsh

somebody knows what does this error mean?

```
Usage: tcsh [ -bcdefilmnqstvVxX ] [ argument ... ].
```

I receive this error after I enter in my script this row

```
#! /bin/tcsh -f
```

Comment: Are you sure the first line of your script is *exactly* `#! /bin/tcsh -f`?  I get a similar error if I use an unrecognized option, such as `-Z`, rather than `-f`.  What is the output of `head -1 your-script | cat -A`?

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't seem like an actual error. If there would be an error bash should have said something like `` bash: error importing function definition for `module' `` what Linux System are you running on the shell? There's often documentation on error messages try command `error info` or browse the manual by command `man -h`.